# Override a service definition in Nix?

Tags: nix, nixops

I'm writing a deployment definition in NixOps. As part of that definition, I need to modify an existing service definition that's provided by `<nixpkgs>`.

I *can't* configure the service to do what I want. Because the service definition itself defines some derivations that I need to modify, I can't just add on my own derivation. The only solution I can see is to override the service definition itself, vendoring in a patched copy.

But if I just try

```hs
options.services.<myservice> = ... # new service definition
```

Nix complains that I'm re-defining all the service options.

If I do

```hs
options.services.<myservice>.override = ...
```

Then the changes to the service definition aren't reflected in my use of
`services.<myservice>` later on (specifically, I define new options, but they can't be used).

How can I actually tell Nix that I want to override the service definition, so I can vendor in my own version of the service?

#### Motivation

The Grafana service provided by `nixpkgs` is incomplete. You can't [provision notifiers](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#alert-notification-channels), and because the [service definition controls provisioning](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/a058d005b3cbb370bf171ebce01839dd6ff52222/nixos/modules/services/monitoring/grafana.nix#L536), you can't manually modify the filesystem - you have to control [the provisioning derivation](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/a058d005b3cbb370bf171ebce01839dd6ff52222/nixos/modules/services/monitoring/grafana.nix#L67).

There's a [PR to fix this](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/110942), but it'll take a while before it's merged. In the meantime, I want to use the version from the PR locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [disabledModules](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/#sec-replace-modules) to achieve this.

It will look like

```hs
{
  disabledModules = [ "services/monitoring/grafana.nix" ];

  imports = [
    ./my-modules/grafana.nix
  ];
}
```